# Очистка непустого двусвязного списка на Go

Tags: golang, linked-list

Как это делать правильно на Go (c учетом особенностей сборщика мусора)?

Недавно сделал реализацию этой структуры данных (ну так сказать для практики - раньше никогда не приходилось иметь дела с подобными структурами) и задумался над такой вроде мелочью.

Вот так это сделано в doublylinkedlist из [github.com/emirpasic/gods](https://github.com/emirpasic/gods)

```
func (l *List) Clear() {

    l.size = 0
    l.head = nil
    l.tail = nil
}
```

Вот так у [меня](https://github.com/GarryGaller/goalgo):

```
func (l *List) Clear() {

    for n := l.Back(); n != nil; n = n.Prev() {
        n.next = nil
    }

    l.size = 0
    l.head = nil
    l.tail = nil
}
```

В стандартной библиотеке вообще нет метода для очистки списка.

P.S. Исправил свой вариант по совету **Pak Uula** на этот

```
func (l *List) ClearOld() {

    n := l.Back()
    for n != nil {
        n = n.Prev()
        l.RemoveBack()
    }

    l.size = 0
    l.head = nil
    l.tail = nil
}
```

но оставил его только в качестве напоминания. А основным сделал метод без цикла.

Comment: Ну так первый вариант проще. Это ж go, а не c++, пусть сборщик мусора работает, он для этого и придуман

Comment: Вот тут у меня и вышла непонятка: не будет ли утечки памяти, если мы просто отрежем все ноды от списка? В некоторых Go примерах видел, что люди при ресайзе, например, среза  (удаление элемента по индексу) также зануляли удаляемое значение (nil или дефолтное для типа) и объясняли это именно защитой от memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сборщик мусора в Go прошел долгий путь. Сейчас в нём реализован [`mark & sweep`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/mgc.go#L24) алгоритм. Если совсем грубо, то все глобальные объекты учтены в некотором реестре. Время от времени запускается `mark` алгоритм - от объектов, на которые ссылаются глобальные переменные, перебирают все достижимые обеъкты и помечают их как "живые". Затем запускается `sweep` - все объекты из глобального реестра, непомеченные как живые, удаляются.

В вашем случае это означает, что те объекты, которые вы храните в вашем списке,  после присваиваний `l.head = nil; l.tail = nil` станут недоступны через переменную `l` и в очередной фазе `mark` не будут помечены как живые. Соответственно, в последующей фазе `sweep` они будут удалены. Утечки памяти не будет.

У вашего цикла

```
    for n := l.Back(); n != nil; n = n.Prev() {
        n.next = nil
    }
```

есть сразу две пробелемы. Во-первых, если на объекты внутри списка нет ссылок из переменных помимо `l`, то обнуление `n.next` ничего не даст для `mark`, объем работы для `gc` не изменится.

Во-вторых, удаление только `n.next` ничего не даст, так как почти на каждый `Node` в удалённом списке будет висеть ссылка `n.prev`. Нужно удалять оба указателя.

На самом деле обнуление указателей на элементы списка имеет смысл. Но только в том случае, если на какой-то из элементов списка есть указатель вне элементов списка. Обозначим его как `E`. Если `E.prev` и `E.next` не делать `nil`, то все остальные элементы списка, достижимые из элемента `E`, зависнут в памяти. Другими словами, в памяти зависнет весь список, так как у вас список двусвязный. Но обнуление тут тоже не есть гуд, так как `E.Prev()` и `E.Next()` после обнуления вернут нулевые указатели, и ваша программа может навернуться, если не будет проверять возвращаемые значения методов `Prev` и `Next`.

Так что что так, что эдак - есть свои минусы.

Comment: Спасибо за подробные объяснения. Мне было достаточно  :-)